How do I transfer a value from my Javascript game into a Flask database?
i am currently coding a Javascript game within a website that uses a Flask database.
to add some context: i am trying to make it so that the user is able to gain currency (named Lamocoins) from playing the minigame. however, it doesn't seem to work with the current way that i'm trying to code it.
here are the codes:
minigame.js
function handleGameOver(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillText('GAME OVER', 270, 230);
    ctx.fillText('You have gained ' + score*2 + ' Lamocoins!', 70, 300);
    gameOver = true;
    fetch('/gain_currency', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: {'score': score},
    })
    .then(response => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                location.reload();
            }, 1000);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}

note: this function is not connected to a button. it happens whenever the player collides with an enemy.
app.py
@app.route('/gain_currency', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def gain_currency():
    data = request.get_json()
    score = data['score']
    current_user.currency_balance += score
    db.session.commit()

here is the picture of the database if that helps:

thank you in advance for answering my question!

"it doesn't seem to work" - What specific operation isn't working as expected and what debugging have you done?  If you're not familiar with your browser's debugging tools, now is a great time to start.

Use JSON.stringify({'score': score}) to convert the object to JSON format.

Fetch API expects your "body" to be a string or something equivalent. You are supplying it with an object.
To properly submit JSON data to server, you'll need to stringify the object into JSON string:
function handleGameOver(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillText('GAME OVER', 270, 230);
    ctx.fillText('You have gained ' + score*2 + ' Lamocoins!', 70, 300);
    gameOver = true;
    fetch('/gain_currency', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: json.stringify({'score': score}),
    })
    .then(response => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                location.reload();
            }, 1000);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}

